# Variables accumulated with checkbox

Tags: c#, sql-server, string, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that shows name, cell phone from a database in SQLServer and that has CheckBoxes. The button will massively send messages to those customers, that's why I want each CheckBox checked to store the variable. The problem is that the messages in the for cycle I sent were not sent.

To send messages in bulk this block is used in string:

```
string bloque = "";

bloque += bloque + "ID1\tphoneNumber\tMessage\n";//client A

bloque += bloque + "ID2\tphoneNumber\tMessage\n";//client B
```

Then I thought I could do it differently by doing a cycle, which would increase the ID automatically for each CheckBox checked and assign the cell phone to the cycle so that when I press the button it sends the message to all the selected clients.

Currently, this is all I have of code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    int contador = 0;
    public Form1(){
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        allID();
        //dtgId.ReadOnly = true;
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        chk.HeaderText = "Seleccione";
        chk.Name = "check";
        dtgId.Columns.Add(chk);
        dtgId.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }

    public void allId(){
        try{
            string cadena = "cadena";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cadena)){
                con.Open();
                string query = "SELECT id, nombre, celular FROM clientes";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                dtgId.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex){
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        List<string> celulares = new List<string>();
        string cel;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgId.Rows){
            if (row.Cells[1].Value.Equals(true)){
                celulares.Add(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());//columna donde estan los celulares
                cel = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();//variable con el celular
            }
        }

        //Codigo para enviar SMS
        string usuario= "usuario";
        string clave = "clave";
        string respuesta = ""; 
        string text = txtTexto.Text;
        string bloque = "";
        //bloque += bloque + "ID1\tphoneNumber\tMessage\n"; 
I try to replace this with the for cycle
        contador++;
        for (int i = 0; i < cellphones.Count; i++){
            bloque += bloque + "ID" + Convert.ToInt32(contador) + "\t" + cellphones[i] + "\t" + text + "\n";          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The DGV may not get repainted.  When you change a DGV you need to set to null to get it repainted : dtgId.DataSource = null; dtgId.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

Comment: Why are you passing the data as a http request rather than saving it to the database directly with ADO.NET?

Comment: So, i should add this line: `dtgId.DataSource = null;`? @jdweng

Comment: Yes to make sure the DGV is getting updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what you are trying to do, however, from what I can decipher, When the form loads it appears to call a non-existent method `allID`? … I will assume you mean `allId` which fills the grid with three (3) columns of data: id, name and cellular.

Then, a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` is “added” to the grid. This will add the check box column as the “last” column in the grid, which in this example, would be at index three (3).

I assume that in the button click event, you want to grab all the rows that have the check box column “checked.” The posted `button2_Click` event is confusing and I am guessing I am missing something that has not been explained.

For starters it is unclear what the `cellphones` variable IS… I will assume you mean the `List<string> celulares`???

In the first `foreach` loop through the rows in the grid, it appears to be adding the first [0] cell value (ID) to the `celulares` list if the value in cell [1] (name) is `true`???

Given this from the posted code it would appear that the `if` statement….

```
if (row.Cells[1].Value.Equals(true))
```

WILL ALWAYS FAIL since the cell value at index one [1] is the `name` field and will never be true.

Next the second `for` loop appears to loop through all the items in the `celulares` list and concatenates those lines into a single string `bloque`. It is unclear what all the other “unused” variables are for. And it is unclear why you need two (2) loops for this.

It appears that the goal here is to fill the `bloque` string with all the ID’s from all the checked rows in the grid. I haven’t a clue what the `Contador` variable is for.

To keep things simple. Below is an example that simply grabs all the info from each row that is “checked” and adds this info to the ‘bloque’ string along with the mass text. I am guessing that if you want to send the “same” message to all the customers, then putting the “same” message for each customer into the list is unnecessary. The example below is going to add the same message for each customer.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  allID();
  DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
  chk.HeaderText = "Select";
  chk.Name = "check";
  dtgId.Columns.Add(chk);
  dtgId.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
}

public void allID() {
  try {
    dtgId.DataSource = GetTable();
  }
  catch (SqlException ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
  }
}

private DataTable GetTable() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("CellPhone", typeof(string));
  for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    dt.Rows.Add(i, "name_" + i, "cellPhone_" + i);
  }
  return dt;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  StringBuilder bloque = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgId.Rows) {
    if (row.Cells["check"].Value != null && row.Cells["check"].Value.Equals(true)) {
      bloque.AppendLine("ID: " + row.Cells["ID"].Value + "\t" + row.Cells["Name"].Value + "\t" + row.Cells["CellPhone"].Value + "\t" + txtTexto.Text);
    }
  }
  // unclear what you want to do with bloque...?
  textBox1.Text += bloque.ToString();
  textBox1.Text += "---------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) With the code snippet from StringBuilder bla bla bla I could solve the problem